# How is Newtonian mechanics valid in waves and ocean currents?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, waves, continuum-mechanics

Can we apply the Newtonian laws only for rigid bodies?

Comment: -1. Not clear what your difficulty is. Why do you think Newtonian Mechanics might not apply? Or are you asking *how it can be applied*?

Answer (score 2):

Newton's laws always apply (well, as long as we stay away from relativistic speeds). In the case of fluids we consider the momentum and energy of small volume elements of the fluid. When we apply Newton's laws to these this ends up deriving the [Navier-Stokes equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations), and these describe the motion of the fluid.

The Navier-Stokes equations are famously complicated and difficult to solve, so using Newton's laws for fluids is a great deal more complicated than it is for rigid objects. Nevertheless the same laws still apply.